# VisualSearch.js: How can I disable?

Tags: javascript

I use this component in my web site.

http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/

How can I disable this object via Javascript?

He has no property or method to be disabled.

**The code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var visualSearch = VS.init({
      container : $('.visual_search'),
      query     : '',
      callbacks : {
        search       : function(query, searchCollection) {},
        facetMatches : function(callback) {},
        valueMatches : function(facet, searchTerm, callback) {}
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This code creates an object called "visualSearch". So I want to disable it.

Comment: Please describe the actual problem, relevant code, and what you have attempted.

Comment: @rlemon My problem: I need to set the object to disabled mode, but he does not have any explicity method or property to do this. The code was edited above

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The above object creates a sub-object named "search". Within this second object, many others are also created. And it works with Backbone which uses the concept of Bind. Thus, analyzing the object code, my solution was to remove all classes as shown below.

Thus, the items (Facets) are shown but the user can't interact with the component.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click-button').click(function(){
        $("#search *").removeClass("VS-cancel-search-box VS-icon-search VS-icon-cancel VS-search-box");
    });
})
```

Comment: Please add explanation ony _why_ this works. Code only answers aren't particularly helpful to all the viewers of this site.